# Python plot a graph from values inside dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, plot

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
test = {1092268: [81, 90], 524292: [80, 80], 892456: [88, 88]}
```

Now I want to make a simple plot from this dictionary that looks like:

```
test = {1092268: [x, y], 524292: [x, y], 892456: [x, y]}
```

So i guess I need to make two lists i.e. `x=[]` and `y=[]` and the first value of the list in the dictionary goes to x and the second to y. So I end up with a figure with points (81,90) (80,80 and (88,88). How can I do this?

Comment: No, as long as the x and corresponding y values are together: (81, 90), (80, 80) and (88, 88)

Comment: @Joel do you have access to the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org) library?

Answer (score 14):

### Use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org) for plotting data

Transform the data into lists of numbers (array-like) and use `scatter()` + `annotate()` from `matplotlib.pyplot`.

```
%matplotlib inline
import random
import sys
import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test = {1092268: [81, 90], 524292: [80, 80], 892456: [88, 88]}

# repackage data into array-like for matplotlib 
# (see a preferred pythonic way below)
data = {"x":[], "y":[], "label":[]}
for label, coord in test.items():
    data["x"].append(coord[0])
    data["y"].append(coord[1])
    data["label"].append(label)

# display scatter plot data
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.title('Scatter Plot', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=15)
plt.scatter(data["x"], data["y"], marker = 'o')

# add labels
for label, x, y in zip(data["label"], data["x"], data["y"]):
    plt.annotate(label, xy = (x, y))
```

[image: scatter plot]

The plot can be made prettier by reading the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) and adding more configuration.

---

### Update

Incorporate suggestion from @daveydave400's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30013971/2087463).

```
# repackage data into array-like for matplotlib, pythonically
xs,ys = zip(*test.values())
labels = test.keys()   

# display
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.title('Scatter Plot', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=15)
plt.scatter(xs, ys, marker = 'o')
for label, x, y in zip(labels, xs, ys):
    plt.annotate(label, xy = (x, y))
```

Answer (score 5):

This works in both python 2 and 3:

```
x, y = zip(*test.values())
```

Once you have these you can pass them to a plotting library like matplotlib.

Comment: good *pythonic* suggestion!  I updated my answer to show both; I kept the original implementation for those who have not yet learned about all the various iterating shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

```
def plot(label, x, y):
    ...

for (key, coordinates) in test.items():
    plot(key, coordinates[0], coordinates[1])
```