# Pythonically unpacking nested list values from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013511/python-plot-a-graph-from-values-inside-dictionary/30013971#30013971) goes nearly where I want. However, my dictionary has a list inside a list for each key, such as:

```
test = {1092268: [[81, 90], [78, 90]], 
        524292: [[80, 80], [65, 78]], 
        892456: [[88, 81], [81, 88]]}
```

The suggestion that Works when there is just one list inside each key is:

```
xs, ys = zip(*test.values())
```

How can I unpack (still xs and ys), but from multiple lists?

For the example, the results I expect are:

```
xs = [81, 78, 80, 65, 88, 81]
ys = [90, 90, 80, 78, 81, 88]
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Are you looking for `itertools.chain`?

Comment: Not a perfect dupe, but closing since they _are_ related (I see that now after comparing the answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not much changes, just flatten your values in advance.

## `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain
xs, ys = zip(*chain.from_iterable(test.values()))
```

Of course, this returns tuples. If you want lists instead, I recommend adding a `map` call—

```
xs, ys = map(list, zip(*chain.from_iterable(test.values())))
```

```
print(xs)
[81, 78, 80, 65, 88, 81]

print(ys)
[90, 90, 80, 78, 81, 88]
```

---

## Comprehension-based

This is the alternative, squash nested loops into a single line (i.e., a nested list comprehension)—

```
xs, ys = map(list, zip(*[j for i in test.values() for j in i]))
```

```
print(xs)
[81, 78, 80, 65, 88, 81]

print(ys)
[90, 90, 80, 78, 81, 88]
```

However, I recommend `itertools.chain` because it has been shown to outperform nested list comprehensions, comprehensively (...hah).

Comment: I like this answer using `itertools.chain`. Upvoted.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Always happy to return good sportsmanship in kind. Your answer is quite nice in its own right.

Comment: Just curious: there are any advantages of using `itertool.chain` over `reduce` or `list comprehension` ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Yes. I believe reduce is a quadratic time method for joining lists, as is the list comprehension. The chain method is _very_ efficient, and from my tests consistently outperforms the other two. By the way, reduce is equivalent to `sum(list_of_lists, [])`.

Comment: In this answer there are some tests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/6583140 and it's seems that chain is fastest.

Comment: However, `itertools` package contains functions for creating iterators for efficient looping.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut It finds applications in the funniest of places, including pandas... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use `reduce` method by passing a *lambda* expression as first `argument`.

```
from functools import reduce
xs, ys = zip(*reduce(lambda x, y : x + y, test.values()))
```

A faster way to do the `reduce` version could be using `concat` operator.

```
xs, ys = zip(*reduce(operator.concat, test.values()))
```